# How to bulk re-index the whole site for core search?

Tags: search

I have a website that has about 100,000 nodes.

In the core search page (`admin/config/search/settings`) it shows that:

> **There are 80801 items left to index.**

It index 100 (or at most 500) nodes per cron run but it's useless.

I want to bulk index the whole site (all nodes) for **core** search.

### How can I do that?

The [Reindex](https://www.drupal.org/project/reindex) and [Batch indexing](https://www.drupal.org/project/batch_indexing) modules are created for this but there are only a few users use these modules and I couldn't be sure to use them. And also there is a module called [Elysia Cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) for modifying the cron per job but it's still useless for me because there are thousands of nodes to index.

*(Note: I want to do this for core search not for other search solutions).*

Comment: Reindex module has 257 reported installs; I wouldn't call that just a few people. I suggest making a clone of the site and trying out that module. If something goes wrong, your live site won't be affected.

Comment: @AramBoyajyan you're right. Actually for Reindex module it wasn't about a few it was about the "redness" of the module. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome; redness means that the module is still in development. I do agree that you should generally be more aware of this and look for potential issues, but you will need it only once (I guess) so if it works that one time, you are good to go. Also, always check if there are any critical issues - Reindex doesn't have any.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following drush command.

```
drush search-reindex --immediate --verbose
```